# Conditional to grab parent page thumbnail URL

Tags: post-thumbnails

I'm currently using this code to grab the featured image URL and insert it as a background image:

```
<?php $thumb = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID), 'full' );?>
<div class='guideHeader' style='background-image: url(<?php echo $thumb['0']; ?>);'>
```

What I'd like to do is make this a conditional:

1. If Parent Page > Insert Thumbnail URL.
2. If child of Parent and has no featured image > insert parent thumbnail URL.
3. If child of Parent and has featured image > Insert Thumbnail URL.

Comment: You really only need to do something different in case 2. You'll need [`has_post_thumbnail()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/has_post_thumbnail) and [`get_ancestors()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_ancestors) (the page's immediate parent will be the zeroth element of the array that `get_ancestors()` returns).

Comment: Sorry, can you show me what this would look like? I'm still fairly new to WP. I follow what you're saying but no idea how to translate that to the proper code.

Comment: Sure. I added an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<?php 
$id = $post->ID;
if( ! has_post_thumbnail( $id ) ) {
    // the current page has no feature image
    // so we'll see if a) it has a parent and b) the parent has a featured image
    $ancestors = get_ancestors( $post->ID, 'page' );
    $parent_id = $ancestors[0];
    if( has_post_thumbnail( $parent_id ) ) {
        // we'll use the parent's featured image
        $id = $parent_id;
    }

}
$thumb = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id($id), 'full' );
?>
<div class='guideHeader' style='background-image: url(<?php echo $thumb['0']; ?>);'>
```

The result is that, if the current page has a featured image set, that will be used. If it doesn't, but it *does* have a parent page, then we'll check to see if that parent has a featured image. If it does, we'll use that page's `ID` to get the featured image. If the parent page *doesn't* have a featured image, then we'll just use the current page's `ID` and let  the chips fall where they may.

This is quick and dirty, and does no real error handling. (A glance at the Codex pages for `get_post_thumbnail_id()` and `wp_get_attachment_image_src()` indicates that they'll both return `false` if there's no featured image, which means that in the worst case your page won't have  a background image.)

### References

- [`get_ancestors()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_ancestors)
- [`has_post_thumbnail()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/has_post_thumbnail)
- [`get_post_thumbnail_id()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_thumbnail_id)
- [`wp_get_attachment_image_src()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_attachment_image_src)

Comment: This works perfectly. I had the right idea in my head but I was WAY off with my implementation. The pages we use this one will always have a featured image at least on the parent level so that should be fine.

Comment: If you haven't yet -- bookmark the [WordPress Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/) (especially the [Function Reference](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference)).